# Any good frameworks for mobile?

Tags: mobile, mobile-development

Nice hybrid framework for both android/ios? I tried `ionic framework` and it's super easy to use but it slow compared to native framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check this framework https://www.nativescript.org/

and read it's documentation https://docs.nativescript.org/

It can be integrated using `vanilla javascript`, `angular` or `vue`